# PHP mysqli data in a table with delete button to jQuery modal confirm, then $.post to PHP to execute mysqli delete and refresh parent page

Tags: php, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog, dynamic-data, page-refresh

Here's the workflow I'm trying to accomplish.

On my Users.html page load, I execute php code to fetch data from the mysql database, then create a dynamic table using php to loop and create the table rows and data elements for each row.

On each row is a delete button; upon pressing the delete button, I open a jQuery UI modal dialog box with the user data passed in and displayed in the dialog box.

If the user hits confirm to delete the user, I use $.post to open a php page and pass the data for the php page to execute the user delete.

Upon successful delection (or error) I use header "users.html?error=x" where x is the error number so the user ends back at the original users.html page where they started.

The problem is the users.html page never gets refreshed (and the page never actually changes during the whole modal-php redirect process.

I used a (#divIDx).remove() to remove the entry in the table, but since it is a dynamic table, when the user changes pages on the table or resorts or selects to allow more or less entries per page, the user comes back even though they have been deleted from the database.  I tried calling document.location.reload() as a result of the user hitting the confirm delete button but my security hears that call and kills the current session.

So to break it down   HTML anchor click -> jquery dialog box -> remove users php -> back to same users.html  but the users.html never refreshes.

Here's the users.html where the database query is executed

```
<?php
    require_once( '_/connections/login.php' );

    $stmt = $mysqli_login->stmt_init();
    //$businessid =  $mysqli_login->real_escape_string($orgid);
    $stmt = $mysqli_login->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, role, email, id, organizationid FROM login where organizationid = " . $mysqli_login->real_escape_string($orgid) );
    //$stmt = $mysqli_login->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, role, email, id, organizationid FROM login where organizationid = ?");
    if(!isset($stmt)){}else{
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //TODO: find out why bind_params is not working here
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //$stmt->bind_params('s', $businessid);
        $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($Ufirstname, $Ulastname, $Urole, $Uemail, $Uid, $Uorgid);
    }
?>
```

Then I create my table using this code

```
<?php if(!$stmt){echo $users_found = 0;} else {$users_found = $stmt->num_rows;}?>

        <div class="widget">
            <div class="whead">
                <h6>Registered Dashboard Users: 
                    <?php echo $users_found; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <?php if(isset($_GET['del_error'])){
                        switch($_GET['del_error']) {
                        case '0':
                            echo "User Deleted";
                            break;
                        case '1':
                            echo "Error deleting user";
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            echo "Error deleting user";
                            break;
                        case '3':
                            echo "Error deleting user";
                            break;
                        default:

                            break;
                        }
                    }?>
                </h6>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="dyn" class="hiddenpars">
                <a class="tOptions" title="Options"><img src="images/icons/options" alt="" /></a>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dTable" id="dynamic">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>First Name<span class="sorting" style="display: block;"></span></th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php while ($stmt->fetch()) { ?>
                        <tr id="div<?php printf ("%s", $Uid); ?>">
                            <td><?php printf ("%s", $Ufirstname); ?></td>
                            <td><?php printf ("%s", $Ulastname);  ?></td>
                            <td><?php printf ("%s", $Urole);      ?></td>
                            <td><?php printf ("%s", $Uemail);     ?></td>
                            <td class="tableActs">
                                <a class="usereditbutton tablectrl_small bDefault tipS" title="Edit"
                                user-dlg-divid="div<?php printf ("%s", $Uid); ?>"
                                user-dlg-fname="<?php printf ("%s", $Ufirstname); ?>" 
                                user-dlg-lname="<?php printf ("%s", $Ulastname); ?>"
                                user-dlg-role="<?php printf ("%s", $Urole); ?>"
                                user-dlg-email="<?php printf ("%s", $Uemail); ?>"
                                user-dlg-id="<?php printf ("%s", $Uid); ?>" 
                                user-dlg-orgid="<?php printf ("%s", $Uorgid); ?>"
                                ><span class="iconb" data-icon="&#xe1db;"></span></a>
                                <a class="userdeletebutton tablectrl_small bDefault tipS" title="Remove" 
                                user-dlg-divid="div<?php printf ("%s", $Uid); ?>"
                                user-dlg-fname="<?php printf ("%s", $Ufirstname); ?>" 
                                user-dlg-lname="<?php printf ("%s", $Ulastname); ?>"
                                user-dlg-role="<?php printf ("%s", $Urole); ?>"
                                user-dlg-email="<?php printf ("%s", $Uemail); ?>"
                                user-dlg-id="<?php printf ("%s", $Uid); ?>" 
                                user-dlg-orgid="<?php printf ("%s", $Uorgid); ?>"
                                ><span class="iconb" data-icon="&#xe136;"></span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } $stmt->close(); ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The form div is simple because I dynamically inject the HTML from another HTML page

```
<div id="dialog_edituser" title="Edit User Form">
    <a id="dialog_edituser_content"></a>
</div>
```

The javscript code for the dialog box gets the values for the necessary parameters, stores them in a few globals, then upon opening, the contents of the HTML are injected into the proper div with the server already filling in the required dynamical data using a few echo $_POST['...'] commands

```
//==================================//
//===== Remove User Dialog Box =====//
//==================================//
var dialog_deluser_divid = ''; //tr to delete from table
var dialog_deluser_fname = ''; //first name
var dialog_deluser_lname = ''; //last name
var dialog_deluser_email = ''; //email
var dialog_deluser_role = ''; //role
var dialog_deluser_id = ''; //id
var dialog_deluser_orgid = ''; //business id
$('#dialog_deluser').dialog({
    autoOpen: false, 
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
            "Submit": function() {
                //remove the data from the table
                $('#'+dialog_deluser_divid).remove();
                //remove the user from the database
                $.post("_/processUserRemove.php", { 
                    'fname': dialog_deluser_fname, 
                    'lname': dialog_deluser_lname,
                    'email': dialog_deluser_email,
                    'role': dialog_deluser_role,
                    'id': dialog_deluser_id,
                    'orgid': dialog_deluser_orgid
                });
                //close the dialog box
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
    },
    //load the dialog box with the contents of an HTML file replacing the ID in a <div id=
    open: function(event, ui) {
           $('#dialog_deluser_content').load('_/processUserRemoveDialog.html', 
           {'divid':dialog_deluser_divid,
            'fname':dialog_deluser_fname, 
            'lname':dialog_deluser_lname,
            'email':dialog_deluser_email,
            'role':dialog_deluser_role,
            'id':dialog_deluser_id,
            'orgid':dialog_deluser_orgid},
            function() {
           });
   }

});

$('.userdeletebutton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dialog_deluser_divid = $(this).attr("user-dlg-divid");//id of tr to delete
    dialog_deluser_fname = $(this).attr("user-dlg-fname");//set first name
    dialog_deluser_lname = $(this).attr("user-dlg-lname");//set last name
    dialog_deluser_email = $(this).attr("user-dlg-email");//set email
    dialog_deluser_role = $(this).attr("user-dlg-role");//set role
    dialog_deluser_id = $(this).attr("user-dlg-id");//set id
    dialog_deluser_orgid = $(this).attr("user-dlg-orgid");//set organization id;
    $('#dialog_deluser').dialog('open');
});
//===== End Remove User Dialog Box =====//
```

Once the user hits the Submit button the values are posted to the processUserRemove.php and the processUserRemove.php will execute header('Location: ../users.html?del_error=x'); where 'x' is the appropriate error number.

Here is the processUserRemove.php code

```
<?php
require_once( './connections/login.php' );
require_once( 'login_functions.php' );
sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a php session. 

if(isset($_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['role'], $_POST['id'],             $_POST['orgid'])) {
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//TODO: get the associated business ID from the current user
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$RUfirstname = $_POST['fname'];
$RUlastname = $_POST['lname'];
$RUemail = $_POST['email'];
$RUrole = $_POST['role'];
$RUid = $_POST['id'];
$RUorgid = $_POST['orgid'];
$RU_currentuser_orgid = $_SESSION['organizationid'];
$del_stmt = $mysqli_login->init();
if ($RU_currentuser_orgid == $RUorgid) {
    if ($del_stmt = $mysqli_login->prepare("DELETE FROM login WHERE firstname = ? and lastname = ? and email = ? and role = ? and organizationid = ? and id = ?")) {    
       $del_stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $RUfirstname, $RUlastname, $RUemail, $RUrole, $RUorgid, $RUid); 
       // Execute the prepared query.
       $del_stmt->execute();
       header('Location: ../index.html'); 
    } else {
        // Registration Failed
        header('Location: ../users.html?del_error=1');
    }
} else {
  //  orgainization id's don't match
  header("Location: ../users.html?del_error=2_firstname=" . $RUfirstname . "_lastname=" . $RUlastname  . 
        "_email=" . $RUemail . "_role=" . $RUrole . "_organizationid=" . $RUorgid . "_id=" . $RUid . "_cuid=" . $RU_currentuser_orgid); 
}
} else { 
// The correct POST variables were not sent to this page.
header('Location: ../users.html?del_error=3'); 
}
?>
```

But during the whole process of button -> modal -> php -> users.html, the users.html page never refreshes.  Removing the table entry works, but when the user interacts with the table the deleted data comes back, and the document.location.reload(true) logs me out of my system?!?

Sorry for all the code but I wanted to be perfectly clear how I'm missing something or how incredibly complex I've made what should be a simple operation.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.